# Make my caption at the middle bottom of the image

Tags: graphics

I would like to make the captions at the middle bottom of the image. This is my code:

```
\newlength{\tempdima}
\begin{figure}
\setlength{\tempdima}{2.1cm}% specify height
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rcc}
\includegraphics[height=\tempdima]{step1.png} &
\includegraphics[height=\tempdima]{step2.png} \\
& A & \textsl{$E_{s}$}\\
\includegraphics[height=\tempdima]{step3.png} &
\includegraphics[height=\tempdima]{step4.png} \\
& \textsl{$E_{n}$} & \textsl{$E$}\\
\includegraphics[height=\tempdima]{step5.png} &
\includegraphics[height=\tempdima]{step6.png} \\
\textsl{$\frac{denoise(E_{s})}{denoise(E_{n})}$} & 
\textsl{$A\times\frac{denoise(E_{s})}{denoise(E_{n})}$}\\
\sbox0{}%
\end{tabular}
\caption{Different stage of the algorithm}
\label{fig:fig}
\end{figure}
```

And the result is:
[image]

It seems my caption is placed at right of my image. Why?

Comment: I don't think so, if we speak of the same caption(Fig. 8, &c.)

Comment: You define three columns `{rcc}` and then only put content in two from each row, but for the images you put them in the first two and the text is in the last two, with the exception of the final row. Why is that?

Comment: I am curious to know why have you decided to use a table rather than using a normal subfigure environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the captions you are talking about are the `A`, `Es`, `En`, `E`, and the two formulas.

The problem is, you have defined your `tabular` environment to have three columns with `{rcc}` -- a right aligned column, and two center aligned columns. However, you are only using two of those columns in each row, and to make matters worse you are putting the images into the *first* (right aligned) and *second* (center aligned) columns, but the letters are in the *second* and *third* columns (both center aligned). The exception being the formulas which are in the first two columns.

To get the effect that it looks like you're trying to achieve, you simply need to define only *two center aligned columns* -- `{cc}` and remove the extra `&` from the text rows.

Comment: Thanks, it works.